# Spring MVC converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Well, I have a problem when I send data to my `controller`:

```
@RequestMapping("/someUrl")
public String method(@RequestParam Long id) {
    //do something
}
```

So, if I send String "null" I have exception

```
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long];
```

I understand why is so, but how I can change converter? I want the string "null" to convert to null. Maybe there are any another ways to solve this problem?

Comment: I expect a url like this in the first place: /someUrl/{id}. and why do not you convert it yourself in handler ?

Comment: @Neron That's a path parameter, not a request parameter. As for converting yourself, why would you do something like that instead of letting the framework handle it?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion) about how to add customization to the converters.

Comment: I would suggest you to prefer to use path parameter in this one. It is more readable I think. And for the other one, I found this :  http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-using-type-converters-with-spring-mvc/

Comment: You can post your parameter with just a `null` value not a 'null'.

Comment: @Kayaman thank you, this is what I need!

Answer (score 2):

To have null you shouldn't use the parameter in the url and use the required attribut of @RequestParam

```
RequestMapping("/someUrl")
public String method(@RequestParam(required = false) Long id) {
    //do something
}
```

Then request the url like http://example.com/someUrl

Or if you realy need to send 'null' then use a custom converter http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion

Comment: I mean 'null' like a String

Comment: then you need a to customize the converters

Answer (score 1):

Just change the type of the id from `Long` to `String` and do not make it required like @JEY suggested

```
@RequestMapping("/someUrl")
public String method(@RequestParam(required = false) String id) {
   if(id!=null)
      Long l = Long.valueOf(id)
   //do something
}
```